# Difference between would be and might be

Tags: meaning, conditional-constructions

Could you tell me the difference between these two sentences:

> **A**: He would be going to railway station.
>   **B**: He might be going to railway station.

Answer (score -2):

Would be means it will most probably be the case, or to put it another way it means 70 - 30 or 80 - 20. While, *Might be* means any uncertainity, that is, it could be 80-20 or 20-80 too. For example:

1. Joe goes to Sam's place with an uber eat food delivery. Sam can see Joe with food in his hands walking around his block. Joe is uncertain which house is Sam's. Sam waves to Joe and says, *This might be my food*. In this scanario, the chances of the food to be meant for Sam are very high, like 99-1.
2. Conor Mcgregor is gonna fight a fairly low ranked player in the coming UFC match. Sam puts one grand bet on winning of Mcgregor. Joe goes, *Mate!, you better think twice, Mcrgor might lose*. Here the chances of lose of Mcgreror are say 20-80.

Comment: That is so inaccurate to say that "_might be_ means 50-50". _I might be struck by lightning tomorrow. I might be winning the lottery next week. My father might be an alien from another planet. Strawberries might be bad for your health._ All of those statements are grammatical and reasonable, but none of them have a 50-50 likelihood of being true.